# Sleuth TraceId gets lost in Spring State Machine

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, spring-statemachine

I'm struggling with a problem regarding Spring State Machine and Spring Cloud Sleuth. After emitting event to change the state of my state machine, I'm not able to see the traceId anymore. The traceId just get lost.

As example, I have a simple State Machine with only three states:

```
@Configuration @EnableStateMachine
public class StateMachineConfiguration extends EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter<State, Event> {

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<State, Event> states) throws Exception {
        states
            .withStates()
            .initial(State.STARTED)
            .end(State.FINISHED)
            .states(EnumSet.allOf(State.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<State, Event> transitions) throws Exception {
        transitions
            .withExternal()
            .source(State.STARTED).target(State.PROCESSING)
            .event(Event.ANALYZE)
            .and()
            .withExternal()
            .source(State.PROCESSING).target(State.FINISHED)
            .event(Event.ANALYZE)
        ;
    }
}
```

And a controller method with logs to see the states:

```
@RestController
public class StateMachineController {

    @Autowired
    private StateMachine<State, Event> stateMachine;

    @GetMapping
    public void stateMachineTest() {

        log.info("Invoking state machine.");

        stateMachine.start();
        log.info(" --- {} / traceId = {}", stateMachine.getUuid(), MDC.get("X-B3-TraceId"));

        stateMachine.sendEvent(Event.ANALYZE);
        log.info(" --- {} / traceId = {}", stateMachine.getUuid(), MDC.get("X-B3-TraceId"));

        stateMachine.sendEvent(Event.ANALYZE);
        log.info(" --- {} / traceId = {}", stateMachine.getUuid(), MDC.get("X-B3-TraceId"));
    }
}
```

The result of accessing this method is:

```
2020-06-24 17:54:49.212  INFO [spring-sm,c98b3d6a7a0eb04f,c98b3d6a7a0eb04f,false] 4156 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] b.c.l.pf.spring.sm.SpringSmApplication   : Invoking state machine.
2020-06-24 17:54:49.238  INFO [spring-sm,c98b3d6a7a0eb04f,c98b3d6a7a0eb04f,false] 4156 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] b.c.l.pf.spring.sm.SpringSmApplication   :  --- 41ac020d-5c25-4acd-b757-262c4491fcb7 / traceId = c98b3d6a7a0eb04f
2020-06-24 17:54:49.260  INFO [spring-sm,,,] 4156 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] b.c.l.pf.spring.sm.SpringSmApplication   :  --- 41ac020d-5c25-4acd-b757-262c4491fcb7 / traceId = null
2020-06-24 17:54:49.262  INFO [spring-sm,,,] 4156 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] b.c.l.pf.spring.sm.SpringSmApplication   :  --- 41ac020d-5c25-4acd-b757-262c4491fcb7 / traceId = null
```

We can see the traceId was lost after the first event to change the state and I have no idea what is going on. I'm currently using the following versions:

- *Spring Boot* **1.5.21.RELEASE**
- *Spring State Machine* **2.2.0.RELEASE**
- *Spring Cloud Dependencies* **Edgware.RELEASE**

Any ideas/suggestions on that?

---

I've noticed some minutes ago that this behaviour does not happen with *Spring Boot* **2.2.2.RELEASE** and *Spring Cloud Dependencies* **Hoxton.RELEASE**. The same example above results:

```
2020-06-24 09:38:52.781  INFO [spring-sm,e96c38b34cd805bd,e96c38b34cd805bd,false] 7008 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] b.c.l.pf.spring.sm.SpringSmApplication   : Invoking state machine.
2020-06-24 09:38:52.803  INFO [spring-sm,e96c38b34cd805bd,e96c38b34cd805bd,false] 7008 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] b.c.l.pf.spring.sm.SpringSmApplication   :  --- 69de87f9-738e-429a-8e07-8e465260301c started
2020-06-24 09:38:52.815  INFO [spring-sm,e96c38b34cd805bd,e96c38b34cd805bd,false] 7008 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] b.c.l.pf.spring.sm.SpringSmApplication   :  --- 69de87f9-738e-429a-8e07-8e465260301c in processing
2020-06-24 09:38:52.818  INFO [spring-sm,e96c38b34cd805bd,e96c38b34cd805bd,false] 7008 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] b.c.l.pf.spring.sm.SpringSmApplication   :  --- 69de87f9-738e-429a-8e07-8e465260301c finished
```

The big problem here is that I cannot update my "real project" to Spring Boot 2 right now.

Any kind of idea or suggestion will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally, traceId should not lost. Can you examine the MDC context and check for any missing data?

Comment: Yeah @sonus21 it's not getting lost actually, but somehow it's being detached. I just updated the code snippet adding information from the MDC context to the logs.

Comment: Sleuth coming from Edgware is ancient and won't be updated. There's not much that can be done really.